# Drag Highlighting On the Desktop Is not Calibrated Right In 21.04

Tags: mouse, .desktop, 21.04

I don't think that it is possible for me to screenshot an example of this (please let me know if there is a better way), as the mouse doesn't seem to show up in screenshots. But essentially what is happening is that the dragged highlight area on the desktop does not follow the position of the mouse. It is being scaled like crazy. For example, say I drag my mouse to form a small square, the highlighted area will instead be spanning almost the entire lenght of the screen.

Whats also interesting is that the scale factors seem to change based on the monitor. The above example was on a 2560x1440 monitor, but if I did the same on my second 1920x1080 monitor, the incorrect scaling would be moreso vertical as opposed to horizontal, and by not as much.

EDIT: here is a video of what I am talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5zN2.jpg